# signalR chat just working on local network

Tags: signalr

I made the chat example that is described on most of the sites (I followed Hanselman's [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)). The code I use is exactly the same is described there or in the SignalR wiki

It works fine on my local, and when I deploy to my server (shared godaddy hosting) works fine on two computers on the same network, saying both can see each other messages

The problem is when I try to access the example from a different network I cannot see that person posts, even that the same webpage is being used

After doing some research I implemented Groups on my Hub, and I manage that within my server app

My question is, why is this happening? Is this a normal/expected behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have run into the same issue I have, which involves the fact that I am running on GoDaddy's 4GH plan instead of the Legacy plan. After doing some digging on their site, I noticed  that GH appears to stand for Grid Hosting and then later I found this sentence in their FAQ - "4GH 'pools' the resources of many servers and your site's content resides on multiple servers" (http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4883/4gh-frequently-asked-questions). While trying to test with people I found that some people seemed to connect to the same server I was, and other people were connecting to different servers. SignalR does support Redis as a way to help resolve this problem, but GoDaddy doesn't have a Redis service running on their system. I was able to find a place called redis4you.com that allows for a hosted Redis server, but they only communicate on ports 2000-4000 and it appears that GoDaddy blocks the majority of outgoing ports. While this isn't a solution to your problem, I wanted to share with you what I have found to let you know that it appears you aren't doing anything wrong, it is just the way that our hosting provider works.